# Understanding Scala mutable set val reference

Tags: scala

In the book "Programming in Scala", Third Edition, I saw an example that I could not understand. To understand it, I typed it into the scala interpreter:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable

scala> val movieSet = mutable.Set("Hitch", "Poltergeist")
movieSet: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(Poltergeist, Hitch)

scala> movieSet
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(Poltergeist, Hitch)  <<< res3

scala> movieSet += "Shrek"
res4: movieSet.type = Set(Poltergeist, Shrek, Hitch)                  <<< res4
```

My understanding was when doing += on a mutable.Set, the Set should mutate in-place (i.e. the variable to which it is assigned should not change), but the reference changed from res3 to res4.
Also, I understood "val movieSet" to create a value that cannot be changed. Shouldn't this cause "val movieSet" to remain with the res3 reference, and not change to res4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `res3` and `res4` are just additional references to the same object, generated by the scala shell whenever you type an expression with a non-unit return type but don't assign to a variable. When you do `+=`, the method mutates the set, and returns a reference to the same object again, so that's what `res3` and `res4` end up containing.

You can check that two values are actually the same exact object (not two equal objects) using the `eq` method. I.e., `res3 eq movieSet` and `res4 eq movieSet` should both be true.

`val` restricts the variable to always refer to the same object, but it does not restrict that object from mutating in whatever way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Joe K. I was misunderstanding the Scala shell.

Answer (score 0):

`mutable.Set#+=` is has signature

```
trait Set[A] {
  def +=(elem: A): this.type
}
```

That is, it adds an element, and then returns itself, presumably so you can chain calls like `set += "a" += "b"`. The fact that the REPL generates a new `val` for the return is purely because it doesn't know any better. If you had typed in `res3` after that, you would have seen the mutation.